# SBT: possible to read a variable from disk?

Tags: scala, sbt

Is it possible to read contents of file inside sbt?
Say reading a username-pass, etc.

Comment: You could load another scala file that contains that data, I think.  I don't remember how to do it, but I've seen projects with multiple files as part of their sbt config.

Comment: hmm ... I don't want to include it in the project. Like I want to read it from somewhere outside the project, e.g. `~/.credentials`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can read files inside SBT. Look at this example (suppose you have a case class `AppCredentials` defined somewhere in your project):

```
case class AppCredentials(userName: String, pwd: String) // it's better to use Array[Char] for password
val appCredentials = settingKey[AppCredentials]("The application credentials")

appCredentials := {
  val creds = IO.readLines(new File(Path.userHome.absolutePath + "/.credentials"))
  val (user, pwd) = parseCredentials(creds)
  AppCredentials(user, pwd)
}

name := appCredentials.value.userName
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. Slightly confused about "assuming that you have a case class". Suppose I was to include and read a username and password (both string). How should the case class look like? How about the file content itself?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I mean, you should have some class for your credentials like 'case class AppCredentials(userName: String, password: String)'. Sure, you have to parse the ~.credentials file in order to get access to the content (see my edit).

Comment: Another question. Why are we using `settingKey`? Why not use the values directly after parsing the file?

Comment: Sure, you can use all the values directly after parsing. With "settingKey" you can access and use this functionality from SBT.